# How to check multiple conditions in stored procedures for my query using if conditions, what mistakes I made in my procedures?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, if-statement, stored-procedures

Here are my conditions:

1. if workorderi id = 13 -i.e valid number and allworkorderid=' ' then print only one workorderid
2. if workorderid = 1666666 - invalidnumber and allworkorderid=' ' then print invalidnumber
3. if workorderid = 845u485u45u4 - invalidnumber and allworkorderid='yes' then print allworkorderid
4. if workorderid = 13 -validnumber and allworkorderid='yes' then print allworkorderid .
5. if workorderid=845u485u45u4 -invalidnumber and allworkorderid=**'no'** then print invalid character

Every conditions is working except for the fifth one. It displaying both the messages but I want precedence only on string for these condition

For example:

- 133333,'no' should be a invalid character, what ever the number it may be if it is no it should display invalid character .

This is my code:

```
CREATE OR ALTER PROCEDURE Sp_workorders 
    (@workorderid INT,
     @allworkerid VARCHAR(20))
AS
BEGIN
    --this is used to check the id , if it exists below condition will execute or else ,it will print as invalid number
    IF EXISTS (SELECT wo.workorderid, wr.productid
               FROM adventureworks2019.production.workorder wo
               INNER JOIN adventureworks2019.production.workorderrouting wr
                          ON wo.workorderid = wr.workorderid
               WHERE wo.workorderid = @workorderid
               GROUP BY wo. workorderid, wr.productid)
    BEGIN
        --this will run if exists is true 
        IF (@workorderid = @workorderid AND @allworkerid = ' ')
              SELECT Workorders.workorderid,
                     productid,
                     countofoperationsequence,
                     countoflocationid,
                     max_operationseq,
                     max_locationid,
                     completionduration,
                     latedays,
                     category
              FROM   
                  (SELECT wo.workorderid,
                          wo.productid,
                          Count(operationsequence) CountofOperationSequence,
                          Count(locationid) CountofLocationID,
                          Max(operationsequence) Max_operationSeq,
                          Max(locationid) Max_LocationID
                      FROM
                          adventureworks2019.production.workorder WO
                      INNER JOIN
                          adventureworks2019.production.workorderrouting WR
                                     ON WO.workorderid = WR.workorderid
                      GROUP BY wo.workorderid, wo.productid) Workorders
              INNER JOIN 
                  (SELECT 
                       workorderid,
                       DATEDIFF(DAY, startdate, enddate)
                       CompletionDuration ,
                       DATEDIFF(DAY, duedate, enddate) LateDays,
                       CASE
                          WHEN enddate > duedate 
                             THEN 'Delayed Completion of Work Order'
                          WHEN enddate = duedate 
                             THEN 'On time Completion of Work Order'
                          WHEN enddate < duedate 
                             THEN 'Advance Completion of Work Order'
                       END AS Category
                   FROM   
                       adventureworks2019.production.workorder) DaysforCompletingwork ON Workorders.workorderid = DaysforCompletingwork.workorderid
              WHERE  
                  Workorders.workorderid = @workorderid
       END    
            ELSE--Else it will execute this 
              BEGIN
                  PRINT 'invalid number'
              END
     
--it is used to check only one parameter which is string ,whatever the first parameter it ignores it ,it will check only yes.
      IF ( @allworkerid = 'yes ' or @allworkerid=' ' )
      --calling a second procedure which is saved as a seperate file
        EXEC Sp_workorders2
          @workorderid=@workorderid,
          @allworkerid=@allworkerid
      ELSE
        PRINT 'invalid character'
    END 
--Scenarios:
 --exec Sp_workorders 13,'' -- working fine 
 -- exec Sp_workorders 13,'yes'--working fine
 --  exec Sp_workorders 13,'no'--working fine
 --   exec Sp_workorders 137777,'yes '--working fine whatever workorderidnumber it should give only precedence to only yes
    -- exec Sp_workorders 137788,'no' -- not working ,showing both the messages here i want to print message as  invalid  character
```

Comment: Side note: you should **not** use the `sp_` prefix for your stored procedures. Microsoft has [reserved that prefix for its own use (see *Naming Stored Procedures*)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190669%28v=sql.105%29.aspx), and you do run the risk of a name clash sometime in the future. [It's also bad for your stored procedure performance](http://www.sqlperformance.com/2012/10/t-sql-queries/sp_prefix). It's best to just simply avoid `sp_` and use something else as a prefix - or no prefix at all!

Comment: `@workorderid = @workorderid` is not necessary as its always true (unless its null then it won't work). For what you are doing it seems that `@allworkerid` should be a `bit` not a `varchar`.

Answer (score 0):

If you simplify your logic down to a minimal example for testing you can get your logic correct e.g.

```
DECLARE @workorderid INT = 137788, @allworkerid VARCHAR(20) = 'no';

-- This is used to check the id, if it exists below condition will execute or else, it will print as invalid number
IF 1 = 1 -- Toggle while testing
BEGIN
    -- This will run if exists is true 
    IF (@workorderid = @workorderid AND @allworkerid = ' ')
        PRINT('CONDITION SELECT');
END;   
ELSE -- Else it will execute this 
BEGIN
    PRINT 'invalid number';
END;
 
-- This is used to check only one parameter which is string ,whatever the first parameter it ignores it, it will check only yes.
IF (@allworkerid = 'yes ' or @allworkerid = ' ')
    PRINT('CALL Sp_workorders2');
ELSE
    PRINT 'invalid character';
```

And it becomes clear that you have two separate conditional blocks, so yes it will run through both of them. You need to apply the full logic required in each block to avoid double messages. And I would strongly encourage being consistent with using begin/end blocks - while you are allowed a single statement within an if without a begin/end I find it leads to confusion, and bugs if you add a second statement. Finally, remove the unused condition `@workorderid = @workorderid` and make `@allworkerid` a `bit` - since that is how it is used.

```
DECLARE @workorderid INT = 137788, @allworkerid bit = 0;

-- This is used to check the id, if it exists below condition will execute or else, it will print as invalid number
IF 1 = 0 -- Toggle while testing
BEGIN
    -- This will run if exists is true 
    IF (@allworkerid is null)
    BEGIN
        PRINT('CONDITION SELECT');
    END;
END;   
ELSE IF (@allworkerid = 1 or @allworkerid is null) -- Else ignore condition handled by next block
BEGIN
    PRINT 'invalid number';
END;
 
-- This is used to check only one parameter which is string ,whatever the first parameter it ignores it, it will check only yes.
IF (@allworkerid = 1 or @allworkerid is null)
BEGIN
    PRINT('CALL Sp_workorders2');
END;
ELSE
BEGIN
    PRINT 'invalid character';
END;
```

Comment: thanks dale ,based on Your inputs i applied the conditions and it worked,can u please have a look at my updated query, can i have more optimization it .

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Dale for your inputs.

I got the desired output, can you please check and can I have a optimized query for my code.

```
ALTER PROC Sp_workorders (@workorderid INT,
                      @allworkerid VARCHAR(20)=upper)
AS
-- Declare @allworkerid1 varchar(20);
--set @allworkerid1=@allworkerid
--this is used to check the id , if it exists below condition will execute or else ,it will print as invalid number
IF EXISTS(SELECT wo.workorderid,
                 wr.productid
          FROM   adventureworks2019.production.workorder wo
                 INNER JOIN adventureworks2019.production.workorderrouting
                            wr
                         ON wo.workorderid = wr.workorderid
          WHERE  wo.workorderid = @workorderid
          GROUP  BY wo. workorderid,
                    wr.productid)
  BEGIN
      --this will run if exists is true 
      IF ( @allworkerid = ' ' )
        BEGIN
            SELECT Workorders.workorderid,
                   productid,
                   countofoperationsequence,
                   countoflocationid,
                   max_operationseq,
                   max_locationid,
                   completionduration,
                   latedays,
                   category
            FROM   (SELECT wo.workorderid,
                           wo.productid,
                           Count(operationsequence)CountofOperationSequence,
                           Count(locationid)       CountofLocationID,
                           Max(operationsequence)  MAx_operationSeq,
                           Max(locationid)         Max_LocationID
                    FROM   adventureworks2019.production.workorder WO
                           INNER JOIN
                           adventureworks2019.production.workorderrouting
                           WR
                                   ON WO.workorderid = WR.workorderid
                    GROUP  BY wo.workorderid,
                              wo.productid)Workorders
                   INNER JOIN (SELECT workorderid,
                                      Datediff(day, startdate, enddate)
                                      CompletionDuration,
                                      Datediff(day, duedate, enddate)
                                      LateDays
                                      ,
                   CASE
                     WHEN enddate > duedate THEN
                     'Delayed Completion of Work Order'
                     WHEN enddate = duedate THEN
                     'On time Completion of Work Order'
                     WHEN enddate < duedate THEN
                     'Advance Completion of Work Order'
                   END                               AS
                   Category
                               FROM
                   adventureworks2019.production.workorder)
                              DaysforCompletingwork
                           ON Workorders.workorderid =
                              DaysforCompletingwork.workorderid
            WHERE  Workorders.workorderid = @workorderid
        END
  END
ELSE IF ( @allworkerid != ' '
     AND @allworkerid != 'yes' )--Else it will execute this 
  BEGIN
      PRINT 'invalid character'

      RETURN;
  END
ELSE
  BEGIN
      PRINT 'invalid  Number '
  END

--it is used to check only one parameter which is string ,whatever the first parameter it ignores it ,it will check only yes.
IF ( @allworkerid = 'YES'
      OR @allworkerid = ' ' )
  BEGIN
      --calling a second procedure which is saved as a seperate file
      EXEC Sp_workorders2
        @workorderid=@workorderid,
        @allworkerid=@allworkerid
  END
ELSE
  BEGIN
      PRINT ' Invalid character'
  END
```

**Scenarios:**

```
-- exec Sp_workorders 13,'yes' -- working fine 
-- exec Sp_workorders 13,' ' -- working fine 
-- exec Sp_workorders 13,'no'--working fine
-- exec Sp_workorders 135555,'yes'--working fine
-- exec Sp_workorders 137777,'no'--working fine whatever workorderidnumber it should give only precedence to only yes
-- exec Sp_workorders 137885,'' -- working good
```